# Get data file off critical database host

Tags: linux, databases, file-upload

Re-wording this question to hopefully be more understandable. Thanks for the feedback.

We have a data warehouse which sits in our production environment. Our data engineers can get to the host via VPN and 2FA, but otherwise the host is locked down from much of the rest of the environment via ACLs. We would like to transfer a data file off of the host once per day to another host also sitting in that production environment (something that can be done in an automated fashion and not require an engineer to pull the file once a day and manually transfer it).

The data warehouse is not allowed to talk to the internet (nor will it).

Obviously, this would require opening some kind of access between the data warehouse and the other host, but what is the most secure way to go about doing this? Both from the perspective of the ACL and the method of transferring the file?

Comment: You are asking about a secure way of transferring a file from a specific system, but you do not describe the system. It will be difficult for us to devise an answer. It would also help if you described typical file transfer methods and why they will not meet your needs. Otherwise: SFTP on a chrooted directory...

Comment: What do you mean by 'network access'? To the box or from it? If the box itself is allowed to make connections to the outside you can setup a cron job to e-mail this file to someone once a day, for example. If the box is not connected to a network you can schedule off-site backups with third party.

Comment: I re-worded the post as your questions brought to light how unclear I was being. Hopefully, this new one is more sensible!